# how to style contact form 7 dropdown to fit ios

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I've created a contact form 7 form with dropdown/select. I know there is a lot of limitation to style a default select box. For now, it looks ok only on windows.

It seems ios/mac do not accept custom styling on select box, is there a way I can style the select dropdown for IOS/mac? or Can I merge code `<ul> <li>` to the contact form 7?

here is the current styling css

```
/*dropdown*/
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-select{
    
    color:  #7F9D97!important;       
    padding-left: 33%!important;
    padding-top: 20px!important;
    line-height: 90px!important;
 
}
```

I saw many website forms with dropdown using contact form 7 works fine, I'm not sure what is the best way to do a dropdown with contact form 7.
e.g https://symmetrydenman.com.au/

Comment: Maybe adding `appearance: none;` for telling the browser not to use the system widget style.

Comment: thanks, I think that is a solution, while I don't think it's the normal way to do a form. I saw many forms with dropdown using contact 7 works fine, I am not sure how it works.. e.g.https://symmetrydenman.com.au/

Comment: use [select2.js](https://select2.github.io/) plugin for better dropdown style/experience, works with iOS too,